# Pass an Excel variable to a PowerQuery ODBC query IN statement?

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I have an Excel cell containing the following text [including parentheses].... `('A-0','C-1','D-45')` in cell A1. The location A1 is static, but the contents change within the parentheses.

I want to pass cell A1's contents to an ODBC SQL query as below, but cannot get the right syntax (have made the cell a 'named cell' (*named_cell_1* as an example), but I think I'm missing something.

```
Select * from table_1.database_1
where xxxxx IN " & named_cell_1
```

What am I missing to connect the dots?

Answer (score 2):

I created a similar query:

[image]

Which is just:

```
let
    Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=Citibike on SQL 2022", "select top 1000 * from tripdata where LEFT(start_station_name,1) IN " & Query_in_list)
in
    Source
```

The query 'Query_in_list' is pointed at a single cell in my worksheet which has the name 'in_list'. It contains the text "('A','B','C','D')" and this is the query to pull that named cell into Power Query as a value (this is the important part to get it to work with the other query).

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="in_list"]}[Content],
    Column1 = Source{0}[Column1]
in
    Column1
```

In case this is the step that's missing from your setup, you need to use 'Get Data from Table/Range' on your named cell, ensure that 'My table has headers' is not checked, then when you have the single-cell table in the Power Query editor, right-click the cell and choose 'Drill-down'. This changes the query result from a table to a text value.

[image]

The text value can then be referenced and concatenated to your select query.

Answer (score 0):

`IN` needs parenthesis to work.

so simply add them to the query

```
Select * from table_1.database_1
where xxxxx IN (" & named_cell_1 & ")"
```

So if your named_cell_1  conatians 1,2,3,4,5 you would get `IN (1,2,3,4,5)`